# Facing issue while uploading document through protractor

Tags: typescript, file-upload, protractor

I'm trying to upload document through protractor into my angular application, but I'm getting error after clicking on Upload button. 
I'm trying through following code:
const absPath = path.resolve(_dirname, PathofFile);
return $('input[type="file"]').sendkeys(absPath);

Protractor version: 5.4.2
Npm version: 3.10.10
Node version: v6.11.1

Fact is, manually it's working fine. Dragging the file and clicking on Upload button, is uploading the document.

Could anyone help me resolving this issue.

One more thing I would like to add, I tried giving sleep in protractor script and perform upload action manually and it was working fine. I think it's not counting the upload document as correct file or file itself.

Comment: Is the file name textbox visible? That is (manually), can you type in the file name or only drag? Once I needed const bCom1 = 'arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "block"; arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";'; const bCom2 = 'arguments[0].style.opacity = 1;'; await browser.executeScript(bCom1, element(by.id('fileButton')).getWebElement()); await browser.executeScript(bCom2, element(by.id('fileButton')).getWebElement()); await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element(by.id('fileButton')).getWebElement()); and then sendkeys to fileButton

Comment: I haven't tried the above step, but identified the issue in my script i.e., using _dirname in wrong file. Protractor was creating instance in application and showing the correct file name but then after clicking on Upload button file was not getting upload because it can't able to find the file at the wrong location. So I console.log and able to find the wrong path, corrected it and boom! It worked.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const fileToUpload = '../image/dummy.jpg'; // image folder is present in e2e folder of angular project
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    const fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
    fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: This is same as above but the way of defining css is different. I tried you way as well, it's not working though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if you are running on remote machine (like selenium grid or selenoid, or inside container) you will need to use FileDetector, i prepared small script here, to demonstrate:

https://gist.github.com/Xotabu4/13c81465e959974429e2bba9a3408b71

This code will actually send your file over http to machine where browser is located